# Front test - button disabled

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, button, frontend

I am writing a button, which will be disabled after clicked and start 60s countdown before active again.
Here is the relevant JS code:

```js
<GeneralButton variant="contained" disabled={state} onClick={onBtnClick}>
 Resend verification email
 <br></br>
 {state ? seconds : ""}
</GeneralButton>
```

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60);
  useEffect(() => {
    let secondsInterval: string | number | NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
    if (state === true) {
      secondsInterval = setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds((prev) => prev - 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(secondsInterval);
  }, [state]);
  const onBtnClick = () => {
    setSeconds(60);
    setState(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState(false);
    }, 60000);
  };
```

The button actually works, but when I write test code as following:

```
describe("<EmailVerificationPage />", () => {
  it("button should be disabled when clicked", () => {
    render(<EmailVerificationPage />);
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Resend verification email" }));
    // eslint-disable-next-line jest/valid-expect
    expect(screen.getByText("Resend verification email").closest("button")).toBeDisabled();
  });
});
```

it always shows that

```
Received element is not disabled:
      <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium css-1zc34d-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root" tabindex="0" type="button" />

       8 |     userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Resend verification email" }));
       9 |     // eslint-disable-next-line jest/valid-expect
    > 10 |     expect(screen.getByText("Resend verification email").closest("button")).toBeDisabled();
```

is there something wrong? Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state update might take some time to happen. Put the check inside an await waitFor block and see.

```
describe("<EmailVerificationPage />", async () => {
    it("button should be disabled when clicked", () => {
      render(<EmailVerificationPage />);
      userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Resend verification email" }));
      // eslint-disable-next-line jest/valid-expect
  
      await waitFor(() =>{
          expect(screen.getByText("Resend verification 
          email").closest("button")).toBeDisabled()
      });
    });
  });
```